# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mybatis/spring/mapper/MapperScannerConfigurer

Tags: spring

```
@Configuration
public class MainConfig extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebMvcConfig.class};
    }

}
```

`this is my mybatis configuration`

```
@Configuration
public class MybatisConfig {

    @Bean
    public MapperScannerConfigurer mapperScannerConfigurer(){
        MapperScannerConfigurer mapperScannerConfigurer = new MapperScannerConfigurer();
        mapperScannerConfigurer.setBasePackage("com.example.mapper");
        return mapperScannerConfigurer;
    }
}
```

`this is my pom.xml.`

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

when I run the project , it shows the wrong Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mybatis/spring/mapper/MapperScannerConfigurer.
Can anyone give me the solution or some advice how to solve this wrong message?
I have tried to solve this problem for two days,but I also don't have any idea.

I have searched online for the solution,but I don't see anybody get this wrong like me.

Comment: @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{MapperConfig.class};
    }
My mainConfig also add the getRootConfigClasses.